# Why sign in following Change Password in ASP.Net Core 2 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core

The default project template in Visual Studio 2017 contains a function in the ManageController for the logged in User to change their password.

Following a successfull password change the user is then automatically signed in again

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
```

What is the purpose of this sign in?

The full action method is below:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        var changePasswordResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        if (!changePasswordResult.Succeeded)
        {
            AddErrors(changePasswordResult);
            return View(model);
        }

        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        _logger.LogInformation("User changed their password successfully.");
        StatusMessage = "Your password has been changed.";

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ChangePassword));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of [`ChangePasswordAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs#L734), there is a call to [`UpdatePasswordHash`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs#L2315), which itself makes a call to `UpdateSecurityStampInternal`. The implementation of `UpdateSecurityStampInternal` is not important - what *is* important is that this (obviously) updates the `SecurityStamp` property of the user.

Looking into how `SignInManager` works, you'll see that [`SignInAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L188) ends up with a call to `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`'s [`CreateAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L60) method, which itself calls into [`GenerateClaimsAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L75). Inside of this implementation, you'll see the following:

```
if (UserManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
{
    id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType,
        await UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user)));
}
```

This means that after changing a password, the existing `SecurityStampClaimType` value will have changed. Reissuing a sign-in action ensures that a new `ClaimsIdentity` is created, which includes the *new* value of `SecurityStamp`.

---

This may not be the **only** reason for this sign-in action, but it does appear to be *a* reason.